# change the facebook open graph tags site_name , but it didn't take effect in share

Tags: facebook

According to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

I change the open graph tag to `<meta property="og:site_name" content="abcdefg1234">` from `<meta property="og:site_name" content="testupgrade">` , but i doesn't take any effect.

Anyone have any idea?

http://mobdis-test.heroku.com/sites/1999

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be caused by the caching Facebook uses, you can use the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see what the Facebook bot is seeing and to refresh the cache for your URL